# How to encode URL in JS and Decode in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, urlencode, urldecode

Following is my JS code:

```
window.location.href = 'products.php?price_range=-INFto2000,2001to5000';
```

My question is how do I encode the URL in javascript & decode it in PHP, such that my browser's navigation bar will show

> "products.php?price_range=-INFto2000%2C2001to5000"

instead of

> "products.php?price_range=-INFto2000,2001to5000"

and my php code will be able to work with the proper value of `-INFto2000,2001to5000` in `$_GET['price_range']`

Comment: Why should your browser show "products.php%3Fprice_range%3D-INFto2000%2C2001to5000"?!

Comment: @deceze For security purpose. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your javascript code

```
window.location.href = 'products.php?price_range='+encodeURIComponent('-INFto2000,2001to5000');
```

You can access the decoded value in $_GET['price_range']. $_GET variables are decoded by default in PHP.

Comment: How come its not working!!! Check this link - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp

Comment: @satish rajak Though URL is encoded using encodeURIComponent, But PHP is not decoding it, error is  `Undefined index: price_range`

Comment: @MujahedAKAS, definitely it won't show any error message. Check this URL - http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/urldecode/ and add your generated encoded URI into here and check the output.

Comment: @satish rajak; Okay I did it this way;
`window.location.href = 'products.php?price_range='+encodeURIComponent('-INFto2000,2001to5000');`

and its working, is it right way to do this?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent

Comment: `urldecode($_GET['price_range']);` is wrong. PHP will decode data from URLs automatically **before** it puts the values into `$_GET`

Comment: Yes @Quentin first I though URL is not encoded, because after encoding, without decoding everything was working fine, I thought changes are not effecting due to cookies or sometjng, But than I realized We dont need to decode it back in PHP.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `encodeURI()` This function encodes special characters, except`: , / ? : @ & = + $ #`

To `: , / ? : @ & = + $ #` use `encodeURIComponent()`

Best way to encode all characters is to run both functions

```
var url = 'products.php?price_range=-INFto2000,2001to5000';
url = encodeURI(url);// Encode special characters
url = encodeURIComponent(url);//Encodes : , / ? : @ & = + $ # characters
```

By default php automatically `decode` Encoded URLs so you don't have to do anything. You can simply access URL parameters like this

```
 $_REQUEST['price_range'];
```

For some reasons if you have to decode URL Client side you can use `decodeURI()` & `decodeURIComponent()`